# In Haskell, why is this a valid expression?

Tags: haskell

This expression appears to be invalid because the first two elements are lists while the last element is a list of list.

```
[1,2,3]:[4,5]:[[]]
```

But in fact, it does evaluate and is equal to:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[]]
```

How come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider: the following appears to be invalid because the first three elements are ints, while the last is a list:

```
1 : 2 : 3 : []
```

But in fact, it does evaluate!

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or, more directly, and with the same result:

```
1 : 2 : [3]
```

---

`[1,2,3]:[4,5]:[[]]` is just `[1,2,3] : [4,5] : [] : []`

Comment: Then shouldn't [1,2,3]:[4,5]:[[]] evaluate to [[1,2,3],[4,5]] by similar logic?

Comment: @oahz I suppose my contrast is wrong: hang on I'll edit

Comment: I accept your second explanation. The logic now makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
:t [[]]
```

in GHCI

it give

> [[a]]

And `[1,2,3], [4,5]` is `[Int]`,

and so Haskell infer the type of `[[a]]` is `[[Int]]`

therefore, `[Int]:[Int]:[[Int]]` = `[[Int]]`

corresponding, `[1,2,3]:[4,5]:[[]]` = `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[]]`

Comment: Perhaps with even more of a "eureka," note that `:t []` is `[a]`. `a` in this case is `[Int]`, so `a:a:[a] = [a]`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `:` does not separate elements, it is the constructor to prepend an item onto a list (known as [cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) in lisp tradition).

```
Prelude> :i (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]       -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So the value on the right is already the list type that `:` returns. In this case, those are both `[[Int]]`, and there just happens to be an empty list as the last element in the outer list. Because `:` is right associative, `[1,2,3]:[4,5]:[[]]` is equivalent with `[1,2,3]:([4,5]:[[]])` or `[[1,2,3], [4,5], []]`.

The prelude list type has two constructors, `[]` (empty list) and `:` (the prepend constructor). The `[a,b,c]` form is syntactic sugar, as specified in the Translation box in [Haskell 2010 Languare Report sections 3.7, Lists](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-340003.7).

> `[e1, …, ek]  =   e1 : (e2 : ( … (ek : [])))`